# How to structure this OpenGL project

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, opengl-es

I am working on an OpenGL application which does a lot of different things, and I've done most of the code on the non-graphics side of things, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to integrate it with OpenGL in XCode.

There are a few parts to my application

**First, make an object with algorithmically generated vertices**

I make something a custom object which has an array of custom surface objects, which each have custom triangle objects (the triangles are supposed to make it easy for me to tell OpenGL how to paint the damn thing).

**Second, do a bunch of things to that object that OpenGL methods can't do**

I'm talking about 4D rotations and stuff like that, so I have a lot of changes going on that I can't put into a regular GL transformation matrix.

**Third, somehow give the triangles to OpenGL**

Everything works up until this point (I've gotten this to work with Java and 2D vertices before, so that isn't surprising); this next step is where I'm really confused. I'm following the XCode OpenGL template, and they define their vertices like this:

```
GLfloat gCubeVertexData[216] = 
{
    // Data layout for each line below is:
    // positionX, positionY, positionZ,     normalX, normalY, normalZ,
    0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,        1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f,         1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,         1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,         1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f,          1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,         1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
```

If I can avoid the normals, great, but I'm more concerned with the fact that I don't know how I could initialize a GLfloat array like this and then change its values. Maybe I haven't framed this question right, and I apologize for that, but I've been working on this for weeks, and I still haven't come up with a good way to frame the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First about "initialize a GLfloat array": in general creating a large array of data should be done by allocating it in memory. You can simply use

`GLfloat *array = malloc(sizeof(GLfloat)*numberOfFloats)`

or in objective C++

`new GLfloat[numberOfFloats]`

in both cases you need to take care of releasing this memory by yourself by calling `free(array)` or `delete [] array` (C++). By doing this you can reuse the same data array, you can pass it to other objects but mostly I suggest to store it in some objectiveC class (`array` would be defined in its header). You should then allocate the memory on objects initialisation and deallocate it in `dealloc` method. Doing so you will preserve all the ARC functionality.

To go a step further you can create your own `Vertex` structure having all the data you need to define a single point. For instance:

```
struct Vertex {
    float x, y, z;
    Vector3f normal;
    Vector4f someOtherData;
};
```

then use `sizeof(Vertex)` or `new Vertex[]` when allocating an array. You can access any array element by simply calling `array[index]` and you should do all the CPU work directly on the array (unless its size needs to change in which case you should copy the data to a new array). At any time you can change the structure of `Vertex` without breaking the code. This should cover the whole CPU issue.

As for the openGL part it is suggested that each of those arrays you want to draw has its own [VBO](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3ddrawing/conceptual/opengles_programmingguide/TechniquesforWorkingwithVertexData/TechniquesforWorkingwithVertexData.html) (vertex buffer object). After generating the buffer you will need to call `glBufferData` to allocate the memory on the GPU; use `sizeof(Vertex)*numberOfVertices` as a size parameter, as for the data parameter you can use `NULL` if you don't want to transfer the data yet or use `array` if the data are already present in your array. To update the data at any time you can use `glBufferSubData` to directly overwrite part of a buffer or `glMapBufferRange` where you can directly access the GPU data.

As for the drawing it is pretty much the same except you need to bind the buffer and set a correct pointer and stride:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_POSITION, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)offsetof(Vertex, x));
glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_NORMAL, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)offsetof(Vertex, normal));
```

Just a note since your vertex structure will have more data then the openGL will actually need you will be consuming some extra memory on the GPU. To remove it you would need to convert your vertex array to some other data that consists only of values relevant to the openGL but the memory consumption of those data is very small. If you would have 10 extra  `GLfloat` values in your structure and using 10000 vertices at a time it would use about 400kB extra memory.